# Sabbath on Saturday or anyway? Mark 2:27

Tags: sabbath

Is Jesus changing the meaning of what "Sabbath" is for us? Like the sermon on the Mount Mt. 5-7 where Jesus is taking the next step, 
"  You have heard that it was said to the people long ago, ‘You shall not murder,[a] and anyone who murders will be subject to judgment.’ 22 But I tell you that anyone who is angry with a brother or sister[b][c] will be subject to judgment. Again, anyone who says to a brother or sister, ‘Raca,’[d] is answerable to the court. And anyone who says, ‘You fool!’ will be in danger of the fire of hell."

Is Jesus taking "Sabbath" to the mean something different for the NT church from Mark 2:27?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please take a moment to take the Tour where you will notice that questions about a topic are actually off-topic on this site as we concentrate on the actual text of scripture itself. Your question might be more suitable for the SE-Christianity site but it would need to be tailored to that site's requirements, somewhat, as well.

Comment: What is SE-Christianity?

Comment: Stack Exchange - Christianity. [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 3):

The Rabbis and leaders in Christ's day had made the Sabbath a burden for the people by enjoining upon the people countless rules and regulations which God did not require. For them, it was hard work and exhausting labor to try and serve the Sabbath the way that it was prescribed by those Jewish leaders.

Christ, in His message, "the Sabbath was made for man, and not man for the Sabbath," turns this on its head. Rather than abolishing the Sabbath, which Christ never did, He declared simultaneously both the love of God and the hypocrisy of the Jewish leaders. God blessed the Sabbath and sanctified it, giving it unto man as a gift from the beginning. It was given to serve man; to provide man with rest and communion with God on a special day which He set apart and sanctified. He has set up the seventh day, and not another day, as a time of special communion with Himself, and He commands us to rest on that day for our benefit.

God didn't intend that the Sabbath should be a burden. We are not to serve the Sabbath, but the Sabbath is to be of service to us. We are not earning the favor of God by observing the Sabbath; but by receiving the gift that God gives us in honoring the seventh day, we are blessed by God. To refuse this is to refuse the gift and blessing that God is holding out for us to take freely if we so desire.

God is not an exacting taskmaster, but a loving God, who knows what is best for us and provides those things which are needful for our highest good. This is what Jesus was seeking to teach. In giving man the Sabbath, God was giving man that which was for his benefit, and not enjoining upon man some burden difficult to bear. The Rabbis did not understand this, and so they portrayed God to others as they saw Him themselves; harsh, overbearing, and dictatorial. In this they denied the God they professed to serve.

But Jesus showed the real meaning of the Sabbath, and it is the privilege of His people to observe this rest and receive the blessing that God is offering.

**Isaiah 56:1-7**

> Thus says the LORD:
>   “Keep justice, and do righteousness,
>   For My salvation is about to come,
>   And My righteousness to be revealed.
>
> Blessed is the man who does this,
>   And the son of man who lays hold on it;
>   Who keeps from defiling the Sabbath,
>   And keeps his hand from doing any evil.” ...
>
> For thus says the LORD:
>   “To the eunuchs who keep My Sabbaths,
>   And choose what pleases Me,
>   And hold fast My covenant,
>
> Even to them I will give in My house
>   And within My walls a place and a name
>   Better than that of sons and daughters;
>   I will give them an everlasting name
>   That shall not be cut off.
>
> “Also the sons of the foreigner
>   Who join themselves to the LORD, to serve Him,
>   And to love the name of the LORD, to be His servants—
>   Everyone who keeps from defiling the Sabbath,
>   And holds fast My covenant—
>
> Even them I will bring to My holy mountain,
>   And make them joyful in My house of prayer.
>   Their burnt offerings and their sacrifices
>   Will be accepted on My altar;
>   For My house shall be called a house of prayer for all nations.”

**Isaiah 58:13-14**

> “If you turn away your foot from the Sabbath,
>   From doing your pleasure on My holy day,
>   And call the Sabbath a delight,
>   The holy day of the LORD honorable,
>   And shall honor Him, not doing your own ways,
>   Nor finding your own pleasure,
>   Nor speaking your own words,
>
> Then you shall delight yourself in the LORD;
>   And I will cause you to ride on the high hills of the earth,
>   And feed you with the heritage of Jacob your father.
>   The mouth of the LORD has spoken.”

Answer (score 1):

In those cases where Jesus "changed" the meaning of his commandments, it was in the sense of emphasizing the spirit of the law over the letter of the law.

It's not obvious that Mark 2:7 is an instance of this, but if it were, it would have to be in the sense of de-emphasizing the literal physical requirements and emphasizing the mental attitude that Christians should have with regard to the Sabbath.

I.e. it isn't enough to simply refrain from physical labour, one must also cause one's thinking to be about spiritual matters and not have personal worldly thoughts on the Sabbath.  It would be better for one's spiritual thoughts to cause a literal transgression of the sabbath than for one's literal adherence to the law to cause a spiritual transgression of the sabbath.

Luke 6:9 for instance says "*Then said Jesus unto them, I will ask you one thing; Is it lawful on the sabbath days to do good, or to do evil? to save life, or to destroy it?*"  It is obviously better to do a good deed on the Sabbath, even if that means violating the literal letter of the law.

But there is certainly nothing in any of those scriptures to imply anything to do with changing the meaning of, much less eliminating or changing the day of God's sabbath.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus wasn't changing the Sabbath in some sense. The seventh day God rested as stated in Genesis. Essentially most of the bible is pure common sense living for a dysfunctional world. If you don't rest you burn out so Jesus states "The Sabbath was made for man, man was not made for the Sabbath". The danger in a spiritual sabbath is that you put all the emphasis on celebrating God for one day a week when its supposed to be done in everything you do. The idea of resting and setting aside time to celebrate, praise and worship God with Thanksgiving was something Jesus did on a regular basis. He was attempting to destroy the hypocrisy of the pharisees doing whatever they wanted when it suited them and then putting heavy burdens on the shoulders of the lay people. This is the main thing that Jesus was addressing in his comments.